# Mudar Meta Tags dinamicamente angularJS

Tags: jquery, angularjs, html-meta-tag

Estou tentando alterar o `content` da meta tag `Keyword` dinamicamente.
Tenho:

```
<meta name="keywords" id="selKeyword" content="">
```

e estou efetuando da seguinte forma:

```
$("meta[name='keywords']").attr("content", "hello");
```

Coloquei um display na meta keywords e vi que ficou setado o hello, porém quando vou em exibir código fonte vejo que o content ainda esta em branco.

Tem alguma forma de contornar esse problema?

**EDIT: Não precisei efetuar isso no meu projeto mais, porém em nenhuma das respostas consegui efetuar a solução. Porém não estou mais necessitando. Obrigado a todos que me ajudaram**

Comment: Não sei exatamente o objetivo, mas se for pra indexação não adianta muito mudar as meta tags com JS. Quando o JS tiver mudado, os bots já terão lido os valores anteriores e "ido embora". Na verdade, o que acontece é que o JS vai mexer no DOM, e não do documento original.

Comment: Então, eu ate vi um pessoal falando sobre isso já, mas infelizmente sou empregado e o patrão quer isso hehehe.

Comment: @Pizzanio seu problema é o patrão, não a tecnologia.

Comment: heheheh... bem isso, mas consegui convencer ele do quão desnecessário isso.

Comment: @Pizzanio eu entendo a necessidade, mas não é no Angular que mora a solução.

Answer (score 0):

O único *crawler* que interpreta JS antes de capturar as tags `meta` é o do Google - e mesmo assim [não existe garantia de que seu conteúdo javascript seja executado](http://www.simoahava.com/seo/dynamically-added-meta-data-indexed-google-crawlers/).

Uma saída pode ser a interpretação do conteúdo *server-side* antes da emissão para o browser, porém a implementação irá depender da sua plataforma de servidor.